# How to find euclidean distance between keypoints of a single image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get a distance vector d for each key point in the image. The distance vector should consist of distances from that keypoint to all other keypoints in that image.
Note: Keypoints are found using SIFT.

Im pretty new to opencv. Is there a library function in C++ that can make my task easy?

Comment: so, for N keypoints, you'd have N distance vectors to the N-1 other Points ? also, could you explain, what you're trying to achieve with that ?

Comment: What's stopping you? This looks like a straightforward problem; two loops.

Comment: For N keypoints , I should have N distance vectors. Each distance vector in the form of d={d1,d2,d3,.d(n-1)}. I am trying to match two keypoints in the same image.

Comment: Is your problem how to access a keypoints descriptor or how to compute the distance between two descriptors or both?!?

Comment: both. keypoints are stored in a vector<keypoint> datatype.

Comment: are you trying to find duplicate keypoints ?

Comment: are you interested in the euclidean distance of keypoint's ***positions*** or euclidean distance of keypoint's ***descriptors*** (similarity of keypoint's neighborhood)? - I thought about descriptors first, but after reading your question again it might be position distance (which is answered by a-Jays)

Comment: It is decriptor similarity..im looking for. I want to locate duplicate keypoints.

Comment: added a second solution to the accepted answer that will compute the N best matches between two descriptor sets!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you aren't interested int the position-distance but the descriptor-distance you can use this:

```
cv::Mat SelfDescriptorDistances(cv::Mat descr)
{
    cv::Mat selfDistances = cv::Mat::zeros(descr.rows,descr.rows, CV_64FC1);
    for(int keyptNr = 0; keyptNr < descr.rows; ++keyptNr)
    {
        for(int keyptNr2 = 0; keyptNr2 < descr.rows; ++keyptNr2)
        {
            double euclideanDistance = 0;
            for(int descrDim = 0; descrDim < descr.cols; ++descrDim)
            {
                double tmp = descr.at<float>(keyptNr,descrDim) - descr.at<float>(keyptNr2, descrDim);
                euclideanDistance += tmp*tmp;
            }

            euclideanDistance = sqrt(euclideanDistance);
            selfDistances.at<double>(keyptNr, keyptNr2) = euclideanDistance;
        }

    }
    return selfDistances;
}
```

which will give you a  N x N matrix (N = number of keypoints) where Mat_i,j = euclidean distance between keypoint i and j.

with this input:

[image]

I get these outputs:

1. image where keypoints are marked which have a distance of less than 0.05

[image]

2. image that corresponds to the matrix. white pixels are dist < 0.05.

[image]

REMARK: you can optimize many things in the computation of the matrix, since distances are symmetric!

UPDATE:

Here is another way to do it:

From your chat I know that you would need 13GB memory to hold those distance information for 41381 keypoints (which you tried). If you want instead only the N best matches, try this code:

```
// choose double here if you are worried about precision!
#define intermediatePrecision float
//#define intermediatePrecision double
// 
void NBestMatches(cv::Mat descriptors1, cv::Mat descriptors2, unsigned int n, std::vector<std::vector<float> > & distances, std::vector<std::vector<int> > & indices)
{
    // TODO: check whether descriptor dimensions and types are the same for both!

    // clear vector
    // get enough space to create n best matches
    distances.clear();
    distances.resize(descriptors1.rows);
    indices.clear();
    indices.resize(descriptors1.rows);

    for(int i=0; i<descriptors1.rows; ++i)
    {
        // references to current elements:
        std::vector<float> & cDistances = distances.at(i);
        std::vector<int>  & cIndices = indices.at(i);
        // initialize:
        cDistances.resize(n,FLT_MAX);
        cIndices.resize(n,-1);  // for -1 = "no match found"

        // now find the 3 best matches for descriptor i:
        for(int j=0; j<descriptors2.rows; ++j)
        {
            intermediatePrecision euclideanDistance = 0;
            for( int dim = 0; dim < descriptors1.cols; ++dim)
            {
                intermediatePrecision tmp = descriptors1.at<float>(i,dim) - descriptors2.at<float>(j, dim);
                euclideanDistance += tmp*tmp;
            }
            euclideanDistance = sqrt(euclideanDistance);

            float tmpCurrentDist = euclideanDistance;
            int tmpCurrentIndex = j;

            // update current best n matches:
            for(unsigned int k=0; k<n; ++k)
            {
                if(tmpCurrentDist < cDistances.at(k))
                {
                    int tmpI2 = cIndices.at(k);
                    float tmpD2 = cDistances.at(k);

                    // update current k-th best match
                    cDistances.at(k) = tmpCurrentDist;
                    cIndices.at(k) = tmpCurrentIndex;

                    // previous k-th best should be better than k+1-th best //TODO: a simple memcpy would be faster I guess.
                    tmpCurrentDist = tmpD2;
                    tmpCurrentIndex =tmpI2;
                }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

It computes the N best matches for each keypoint of the first descriptors to the second descriptors. So if you want to do that for the same keypoints you'll set to be `descriptors1 = descriptors2` ion your call as shown below. ***Remember:*** the function doesnt know that both descriptor sets are identical, so the first best match (or at least one) will be the keypoint itself with distance 0 always! Keep that in mind if using the results!

Here's sample code to generate an image similar to the one above:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/MultiLena.png");

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(input, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::SiftFeatureDetector detector( 7500 );
    cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor describer;

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;

    detector.detect( gray, keypoints );

    // draw keypoints
    cv::drawKeypoints(input,keypoints,input);



    cv::Mat descriptors;
    describer.compute(gray, keypoints, descriptors);

    int n = 4;
    std::vector<std::vector<float> > dists;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > indices;

    // compute the N best matches between the descriptors and themselves.
    // REMIND: ONE best match will always be the keypoint itself in this setting!
    NBestMatches(descriptors, descriptors, n, dists, indices);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<dists.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<dists.at(i).size(); ++j)
        {
            if(dists.at(i).at(j) < 0.05)
                cv::line(input, keypoints[i].pt, keypoints[indices.at(i).at(j)].pt, cv::Scalar(255,255,255) );
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Micka. Can I ask one doubt? What is the dimension of Mat descr? I have my descriptor matrix of size 4300x128 [SIFT] . When I tried running your code, i am getting out of memory exceptions on runtime.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Dimensions should be right, but Im not sure whether SIFT descriptor elements really are float type. Although the sample output is SIFT too... descr dimensions: Row = keypt. Column = descriptor dimension

Comment: I debugged the code and found that exception occurs at the creation of zero matrix. For images with large number of keypoints, when the program attempts to create large NxN matrix, exception occurs.

Comment: Ah ok... Your descriptor2descriptor distance mat should use 4300*4300*64 Bits = approx 140 MB. You can half the value by using float instead of double. You can half that again by assuming symmetric mat and 0 diagonal.

Comment: How you got the output? Which IDE you are using and what is the system configuration?

Comment: can you tell me what's the size of "large number of keypoints"? Maybe it's not feasible to save "n x n" distance information. But remember that it would consume quite exactly the same memory if you save those information in `std::vector<double>` for each keypoint. I created the output with `cv::imshow("descrSimilarity", resultMat > 0.05)`.

Comment: For the test image im using, iam getting 41381x128 dimension descriptor. MAy be i will have to try without storing the entire distances. After all, for each keypoint, i need to get nearest and second nearest distances to other keypoints only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63763/discussion-between-sparkle-and-micka).

Comment: @Micka I can't get your code to work as it is in your answer, only to show the found keypoints, but not draw any lines between identical areas?

Comment: @MLMLTL does it work (including drawn lines) if you dont change the code? which keypoints do you want to draw?

Comment: @Micka I ended up copying it raw, using a different image to you, but one like yours that had sections of itself copied around, but still no luck.

Comment: changed or unchanged code? with original image it works?

Answer (score 2):

The `keypoint` class has a member called `pt` which in turn has `x` and `y` [the (x,y) location of the point] as its own members.

Given two keypoints `kp1` and `kp2`, it's then easy to calculate the euclidean distance as:

```
Point diff = kp1.pt - kp2.pt;
float dist = std::sqrt( diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y )
```

In your case, it is going to be a double loop iterating over all the keypoints.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a 2D vector (size of which would be NXN) -->
   `std::vector< std::vector< float > > item;`
2. Create 2 for loops to go till the number of keypoints (N) you have
3. Calculate distances as suggested by a-Jays

   `Point diff = kp1.pt - kp2.pt;
   float dist = std::sqrt( diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y );`
4. Add this to vector using push_back for each keypoint --> N times.