# Finding multiple objects in an image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-manipulation, homography

I am trying to find out if an image contains multiple objects of the same type/kind using opencv , More concretely the problem that I want to solve is associating one item from my database to an image :

- a phone -> should be associated with an image of one phone not an image containing 3 phones having different coulors.

So I thought that the first step is to recognize if there is a recurring pattern ( that I don't know beforehand)  and build up on that . the objects inside the image  can also be stacked next to each other (overlapping ) . 
Is there a way to achieve that using opencv?

Comment: what do you mean by "same type"? whether there are 3 dogs in a photography? or "same/similar looking objects"? Have a look at my answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310914/recognize-recurring-images-into-a-larger-one/34314697#34314697 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543880/how-to-find-euclidean-distance-between-keypoints-of-a-single-image-in-opencv/26547225#26547225

Comment: Thank you @Micka I reformulated my question ; 3 dogs of the same breed in a photography

Comment: very hard task from my understanding. Since you would need some scene understanding to solve it. Although the three dogs might have similar color distribution they will still look different from both, color and perspective/orientation. But finding similar items from a database could be approached with SIFT and a bag-of-words method. No idea how well it would work in your specific task.