# OpenCV feature matching multiple objects

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, orb

How can I find multiple objects of one type on one image.
I use ORB feature finder and brute force matcher (opencv = 3.2.0).

My source code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = cv2.imread('box.png', 0)  # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('box1.png', 0) # trainImage

#img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Initiate ORB detector
# 
orb = cv2.ORB_create(10000, 1.2, nlevels=9, edgeThreshold = 4)
#orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

des1 = np.float32(des1)
des2 = np.float32(des2)

# matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, 2)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>3:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 2)

    if M is None:
        print ("No Homography")
    else:
        matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

        h,w = img1.shape
        pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

        img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
    print ("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                   flags = 2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)

plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

But it can find only one instance of query image.

**Query Image**

[image: Query Image]

**Test Image**
[image: Test Image]

**Result**
[image: Result]

So its found only one image from two.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Find the first object, compute transformation, mask area of the found object, repeat until you get all the objects.

Comment: @m3h0w Thank you!

Comment: @m3h0w, may be: 1. calculate features 2. compute transformation 3. find first object 4. mask area repeat until get all objects

Comment: yeah that sounds like a plan.

Comment: @m3h0w may be you know, why matcher can find only one object of two on test image

Comment: Haven't got time to read the docs right now but I think that it is a fair assumption that the matching algorithm is looking for the best matching object and not for multiple objects.

Comment: @m3h0w Thank you!

Comment: @V.Gai You can also check in the literature what are the common approaches to deal with this situation (strict feature matching deals with matching descriptors, there is no object assumption). The SIFT paper of Lowe proposes an approach based on Hough voting. I found recently this paper: [MAC-RANSAC: a robust algorithm for the recognition of multiple objects](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00466487v2/document) but it should exist many others.

Comment: maybe you can adapt my ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543880/how-to-find-euclidean-distance-between-keypoints-of-a-single-image-in-opencv/26547225#26547225 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310914/recognize-recurring-images-into-a-larger-one/34314697#34314697 from similar tasks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My source to find multiple objects using ORB descriptors

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = cv2.imread('box.png', 0)  # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('box1.png', 0) # trainImage

orb = cv2.ORB_create(10000, 1.2, nlevels=8, edgeThreshold = 5)

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth

x = np.array([kp2[0].pt])

for i in xrange(len(kp2)):
    x = np.append(x, [kp2[i].pt], axis=0)

x = x[1:len(x)]

bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(x, quantile=0.1, n_samples=500)

ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True, cluster_all=True)
ms.fit(x)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_

labels_unique = np.unique(labels)
n_clusters_ = len(labels_unique)
print("number of estimated clusters : %d" % n_clusters_)

s = [None] * n_clusters_
for i in xrange(n_clusters_):
    l = ms.labels_
    d, = np.where(l == i)
    print(d.__len__())
    s[i] = list(kp2[xx] for xx in d)

des2_ = des2

for i in xrange(n_clusters_):

    kp2 = s[i]
    l = ms.labels_
    d, = np.where(l == i)
    des2 = des2_[d, ]

    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
    index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
    search_params = dict(checks = 50)

    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

    des1 = np.float32(des1)
    des2 = np.float32(des2)

    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, 2)

    # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
    good = []
    for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
            good.append(m)

    if len(good)>3:
        src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 2)

        if M is None:
            print ("No Homography")
        else:
            matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

            h,w = img1.shape
            pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
            dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

            img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

            draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0),  # draw matches in green color
                               singlePointColor=None,
                               matchesMask=matchesMask,  # draw only inliers
                               flags=2)

            img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)

            plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'), plt.show()

    else:
        print ("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
        matchesMask = None
```

Result images

[image: Result 1]

[image: Result 2]

[image: Result 3]

Comment: Your answer is the best over all the searching, but I need a c++ implementation, I can't find alternatives of  the `estimate_bandwidth` and  `MeanShift` in c++, could you point me out? How can I segment the found good matches to clusters in c++?Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! I think you can find MeanShift for c++ here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga432a563c94eaf179533ff1e83dbb65ea. And about clustring here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html

Comment: That `MeanShift` is far different with the one in `Python` `scikit.lean`, it used to track object in camera and can not track multiple objects. While the `kmeans` of `OpenCV` needs to estimate the clusters count first, this situation made me helpless.

Comment: I post my trying to this thread, would you please take a look at it? Very appreciate it, you way is much too perfect!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425355/how-to-detect-multiple-objects-with-opencv-in-c

Answer (score 1):

To solve this task can be used next approaches:

1. [SIFT (SURF) + MEAN SHIFT](http://answers.opencv.org/question/45888/detection-of-multiple-instance-of-object-with-keypoint-descriptors-brisk-orb/)
2. [Haar Cascades](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html)
3. [HOG + SVM](https://github.com/bikz05/object-detector)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. You can use ORB or SIFT to do the matching. After the first match, the matched area is filled with near-neighbor pixels for the next matching. This can make sure keypoints will not be occupied by the first matching.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def find_matching_boxes(image, template, detector_method, params):

    # Parameters and their default values
    MAX_MATCHING_OBJECTS = params.get('max_matching_objects', 10)
    SIFT_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = params.get('SIFT_distance_threshold', 0.5)
    BEST_MATCHES_POINTS = params.get('best_matches_points', 20)

    # Initialize the detector and matcher
    if detector_method == "SIFT":
        detector = cv2.SIFT_create()
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    elif detector_method == "ORB":
        detector = cv2.ORB_create(fastThreshold=5, edgeThreshold=10)
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported detector method")

    # Find keypoints and descriptors for the template
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = detector.detectAndCompute(template, None)

    matched_boxes = []
    matching_img = image.copy()

    for i in range(MAX_MATCHING_OBJECTS):
        # Match descriptors
        keypoints1, descriptors1 = detector.detectAndCompute(matching_img, None)

        if detector_method == "SIFT":
            # Matching strategy for SIFT
            matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k=2)
            good_matches = [m for m, n in matches if m.distance < SIFT_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD * n.distance]
            good_matches = sorted(good_matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)[:BEST_MATCHES_POINTS]

        elif detector_method == "ORB":
            # Matching strategy for ORB
            matches = bf.match(descriptors1, descriptors2)
            matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
            good_matches = matches[:BEST_MATCHES_POINTS]
        
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported detector method")

        # Extract location of good matches
        points1 = np.float32([keypoints1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches])
        points2 = np.float32([keypoints2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches])

        # Find homography for drawing the bounding box
        try:
            H, _ = cv2.findHomography(points2, points1, cv2.RANSAC, 2)
        except cv2.error:
            print("No more matching box")
            break

        # Transform the corners of the template to the matching points in the image
        h, w = template.shape[:2]
        corners = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h-1], [w-1, h-1], [w-1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        transformed_corners = cv2.perspectiveTransform(corners, H)
        matched_boxes.append(transformed_corners)

        # You can uncomment the following lines to see the matching process
        # Draw the bounding box
        img1_with_box = matching_img.copy()
        matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(img1_with_box, keypoints1, template, keypoints2, good_matches, None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
        cv2.polylines(matching_result, [np.int32(transformed_corners)], True, (255, 0, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        plt.imshow(matching_result, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()

        # Create a mask and fill the matched area with near neighbors
        matching_img2 = cv2.cvtColor(matching_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        mask = np.ones_like(matching_img2) * 255
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, [np.int32(transformed_corners)], 0)
        mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
        matching_img = cv2.inpaint(matching_img, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

    return matched_boxes

# Example usage:
img1 = cv2.imread('i_bast.png') # Image
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

template = cv2.imread('t_bast.png') # Template
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

params = {
    'max_matching_objects': 5,
    'SIFT_distance_threshold': 0.5,
    'best_matches_points': 20
}

# Change to "SIFT" or "ORB" depending on your requirement
matched_boxes = find_matching_boxes(img1, template, "ORB", params) 

# Draw the bounding boxes on the original image
for box in matched_boxes:
    cv2.polylines(img1, [np.int32(box)], True, (0, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

plt.imshow(img1)
plt.show()
```

The workflow is like this:

1. Use the original image to do the matching:

   [image: iter1_image]
2. Fill the matching area with the nearest pixels,and then repeat the matching process:

   [image: iter2_image]
3. Check the result:

   [image: Result_image]

You can also check out my repo:
https://github.com/prob1995/multi_scale_multi_object_template_matching

If you're using my repo for this thread, make sure to modify the matching method to ORB. Like this:

```py
# Change to "SIFT" or "ORB" depending on your requirement
matched_boxes = find_matching_boxes(img1, template, "ORB", params)
```

and params::

```py
params = {
    'max_matching_objects': 5,
    'SIFT_distance_threshold': 0.5,
    'best_matches_points': 20
}
```