# Why is MEAN SHIFT + ORB not detecting (all) multiple objects?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, orb, mean-shift

I have to find multiple objects of one type in an image and for this purpose, I am using OpenCV (Python). First I started with Template matching which doesn't work well if the orientation of the image is changed.

So, I used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938149/opencv-feature-matching-multiple-objects/43023130). But, unfortunately, it is not working as expected and also, everytime I rerun my code, the output (i.e. the bounding box around the object detected) keeps changing.

Here is my output:

[Output(Run 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZT0I.png)

[Output(Run 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMvGS.png)

[Output(Run 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruzLg.png)

[Output(Run 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ztZ.png)

[Output(Run 5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yi9T.png)

[Output(Run 6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wweqr.png)

I have tweaked the values and I am still not getting the desired output. Why is it that 2/5 objects of the same type is detected, but not the rest? 
I have been thinking about ways to fix it for weeks now. I also tried bf.knnMatch instead of flann.knnMatch and SURF/SIFT instead of ORB, but still no luck.

Do you guys have any idea on how can I fix this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Note: I have not made any changes in the code given in the link**