# OpenCV SIFT feature matching within image itself

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I have extracted SIFT features using OpenCV library from an image. Later, I want to match similar key points within the image itself to find similar objects. OpenCv function has two parameters for matching key points from two images.

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
keypoints, descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(grayImg,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(descriptors,descriptors)
for i in range(0, 10):
     matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(grayImg, keypoints, grayImg, keypoints, matches[-10:], grayImg, flags=2)
plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

Also, when I print the values of "descriptors", it shows some encoded values. Can I get any numeric values so that I can compute some distances among those points.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElHAE.png

Comment: you should try template matching, not SIFT

Comment: Have a look at this one. Maybe you can translate it to python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543880/how-to-find-euclidean-distance-between-keypoints-of-a-single-image-in-opencv/26547225#26547225

Comment: @Lamp I have seen template matching. I just want it through SIFT

Comment: SIFT requires unique key points, which is not suitable for this case

Comment: Sift features are corners and their relation to each other. This does not work well for finding similar features within an image.

Comment: So, are there any other methods which can help me except template matching?